# Feed title appearing twice in wordpress responsive theme cyberchimps

Tags: php, rss, wordpress

I am using `responsive mobile theme` by `cyberchimps` in `wordpress 4.1`. When I am trying to read from a feed and display the post on my site, the title is being displayed twice.

I tried changing `feeds-rss.php` and `feeds-rss2.php` from

```
<title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); wp_title_rss(); ?></title>
```

to

```
<title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); ?></title>
```

but the title is still appearing twice.

The url is [Here](http://46.101.161.17/)
Any idea any body?

Thanks

@Rohil_PHPBeginner

My archive.php has this as content and I have no idea which line to edit:

```
 *
 * @package      responsive_mobile
 * @license      license.txt
 * @copyright    2014 CyberChimps Inc
 * @since        0.0.1
 *
 * Please do not edit this file. This file is part of the responsive_mobile Framework and all modifications
 * should be made in a child theme.
 */

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
        die;
}

get_header(); ?>

<div id="content-archive" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main" itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/loop-header' ); ?>

                        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                                <?php
                                /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                                 */
                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                                ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php responsive_mobile_paging_nav(); ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- #content-archive -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The help is appreciated.

Thanks

Any idea anyone?

Nobody yet?

Comment: You have changed the title tag which obvious will not effect. You need to look in to the `archive.php`(if theme has provided or there might be with different name) .

Comment: added my archive.php @Rohil_PHPBeginner any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its difficult because template is linking from one file to another and I think its wrong file(because it is not matching the container div correctly). I can not download the theme as it is not open source.But if you want me to have a look into it you can zip theme files and send me on my mail address : rohilmistry@ymail.com

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner you can download the files from http://cyberchimps.com/responsive-theme/

Comment: Just downloaded the theme from the URL but not able to recreate the issue that you are facing.

Comment: integrate feedpress , and syndicate any site's rss feed to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot everybody. 
I added the following code

```
<style>
h2 {
display:none;
}
</style>
```

in `header.php` and the error cleared out.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose title in header is changed.

duplicated title is displayed as

```
<h1>the text</h1> and below of it <h2>the text</h2>
```

remove one of the header

Comment: That's the question which file to change

Comment: look for from database